# Graphite doesn't display > 6h data?

Tags: graphite, retention, whisper, graphite-carbon

Is something wrong with my config? I log carbon state every minute. It works fine in Graphite, but only for last 6h. If I select anything bigger than that - I don't see any data. This is my `storage-schemas.cfg`:

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 10s:6h,1min:90d

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 10s:6h,1min:6d,10min:1800d
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the retention before or after you started logging data?

Carbon does not automatically resize the data file once you have started writing data to it. So when you change the retention policy, you must manually resize the data file. This is done with the *whisper-resize.py* script.

```
Usage: whisper-resize.py path timePerPoint:timeToStore [timePerPoint:timeToStore]*
```

If you need to resize many files, you can use the find command and pipe the output to whisper-resize.py:

```
find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper -type f -name "*.wsp" | sudo xargs -I{} whisper-resize.py {} 30:7d
```